# Как организовать вывод ошибок при некорректном вводе числа?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть input.

В input должны вводится целые числа.

Моя задача сводится к тому, чтобы показать в верстке ошибки, которые я сейчас консольложу (функция [calculate.js](https://github.com/remenok200/Collatz-conjecture/blob/master/assets/js/utils/calculate.js))

Я понимаю как это сделать, теоретически, но у меня ничего не получается сделать.
Мне нужно создавать элемент с ошибкой, в случае неверного ввода, например, текст над input, а затем, когда ввод будет верный, мне нужно убрать это сообщение об ошибке.

Вопрос: как это сделать?

[Ссылка на проект](https://github.com/remenok200/Collatz-conjecture).

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, что именно у вас не получается? Создать элемент? Делать его видимым-невидимым? Привязать его появление на событие?

Comment: @Mira, делать его видимым-невидимым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом  js  делать компонент видимы - невидимым , так же как и установить любое другое его свойство можно получив компонет по id.

Вот вы создали компонет:

```
<div id="myP"></div>
```

И далее чтоб получить его и изменить видимость

```
 document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";
```